# DC Transmedia Universe: are Man of Steel and Arrow part of the same cinematic universe?

Tags: dc, batman, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

Marvel obviously have a very successful cross-medium Universe, and there are a lot of suggestions that DC are attempting some form of wider Universe themselves.

*Arrow* and *Flash* are both going to share a Universe, with Barry Allen already showing up in *Arrow*; but is there any suggestion that they share the same space as *Man of Steel* and the forthcoming *Batman Vs. Superman*?

There is some suggestion that, as both the [TV](http://screenrant.com/the-flash-tv-series-costume-2014/) and [Movie](http://screenrant.com/batman-vs-superman-batman-costume-ben-affleck-batsuit/) franchises have shown a proclivity to favor the New 52 costume styles, this may be in mindfullness of a strategy to unite the universes, and make sure they are primed to be tonally similar.

Comment: I have read speculation that, aside from being a success in its own right, *Arrow* is a great opportunity for Warner/DC to popularize/establish a less-popular (when compared to Bats/Supes) character like GA without having to invest in a movie for that character first. I think it's a potentially good idea, and one that could be successful for The Flash, as well. To comic book fans, GA and Flash are very well known, but outside, they don't have anywhere near the guaranteed box office pull of Batman/Superman.

Comment: There are rumors the the might appear in batman v superman but nothing is confirmed.

Comment: “DC Transmedia Universe” — mmmm, *transmedia*.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, no. *Arrow*/*Flash* are in their own universe, with the *Man of Steel* films off in their own separate universe. There have been plenty of rumors that Stephen Amell wants to show up in the next *Man of Steel* film, but nothing confirmed.

[A citation](http://io9.com/why-shouldnt-arrow-cross-over-with-the-big-screen-just-1168290743):

> Arrow star Stephen Amell reportedly expressed strong interest in appearing in Justice League a month or so ago — saying he would "sweep the floors" just to be included in the film. His statements were met with shrugs, and there's been nothing more about this since then.

[Another](https://www.facebook.com/stephenamell/posts/676541179097819):

> Hey Guys — I appreciate all the support and enthusiasm, but not everything I post is a cryptic indicator that I'm going to be in Batman V Superman. I'm not going to be in Batman V Superman. - Stephen Amell

[One more](http://www.greenarrowtv.com/arrow-the-flash-will-not-be-part-of-the-dc-movie-universe/18020):

> During the session, [DC Entertainment Chief Creative Officer Geoff] Johns stated definitively that “the film and television universes for DC Comics ‘are separate worlds.’”

Comment: Source? While it is a reasonable assumption, it is an assumption nonetheless. "Nothing confirmed" on Amell in the film is not the same as "not part of the same universe", after all.

Comment: The world affecting events in Man of Steel, you know, alien invasion, devastation of an entire chicago type metropolis, terraforming machines, and widely publicized existence of Superman have made zero mention. Not even a lamp-shade background joke. So it's not an assumption. They are not connected until production or marketing says otherwise.

Comment: @cde I dunno. Starling City sees that level of destruction every year. Their news wouldn't see that level of destruction in another city as being worth covering. (I kid!)

Comment: And [just recently, Geoff Johns described DC’s various TV and movie properties as a “multiverse”](http://screenrant.com/dc-comics-movies-tv-shows-multiverse/), so we can probably expect a *Crisis on Infinite Earths* movie trilogy around 2020.