# Is Supergirl part of the same universe as The Flash and Arrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow, supergirl-2015

The upcoming *Supergirl* TV series is developed by Greg Berlanti, who also developed both *Arrow* and *The Flash*. The three shows also share many other crew members.

Will *Supergirl* be set in the same universe as *The Flash* and *Arrow*?

Comment: Related, not dupe - but only because Keen's answer is now outdated: [Is Gotham intended to be in the same universe as other DC/WB TV properties?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66792/5184)

Comment: There has been no indication in or out of universe. In comics, these things are generally established with a crossover, though even then, they tend to be ignored or reversed later (see DC vs Marvel, Star Trek meets Doctor Who/X-Men/Legion of Superheroes/Planet of The Apes/etc)

Comment: @Politank-Z I'm assuming that the leaked pilot gave no indication either way then?

Comment: Superman was the only other hero alluded to, at least as far as I caught. In the Arrowverse, they've made repeated mention of other DC fictional cities - Central City before Barry's introduction, Coast City often, Ivy Town, I vaguely recall a mention of Opal City... but no Metropolis or Smallville. No reference to crashed UFOs, flying people apart from Firestorm and Ray Palmer, or anything I could construe as a reference to the Superman family.

Comment: Flash has mentioned ferris air and space and that their test pilot disappeared (Hal Jordan).

Comment: Bludhaven has also been mentioned in Arrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now know from the 4 show crossover that Supergirl takes place on (from the perspective of Arrow/Flash/Legends being on Earth Prime) Earth-38. So barring a worlds collide event transporting supergirl to a parallel universe, her show does NOT take place on the same Earth as the other shows.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer! Flash and Arrow are from Earth-1; Kara is currently on Earth-38!

Comment: The question asks whether it's the same universe though, not the same Earth.

Answer (score 11):

We don't know.  It is being produced by the same people who created and run *Arrow*, *Flash*, and soon *Legends of Tomorrow*, which is why there's a real possibility of a *Supergirl* crossover.  However, over the past months, I haven't seen any concrete statements on whether there will be a crossover.  [This article](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/agent-carter-showrunners-grilled-by-759932) says it's part of Greg Berlanti's (one of the producers) deal:

> **Fazekas:** Marc, CBS is doing Supergirl. What is the possibility of a crossover?
>
> **Guggenheim:** It's possible.
>
> **THR:** I actually heard it's in Greg's deal, that Supergirl can cross over with Flash and/or Arrow.

But [other articles](http://movieweb.com/supergirl-arrow-flash-tv-crossover-cbs/) say otherwise.  Nina Tassler, Chairman of CBS Entertainment said:

> That's a different network so I think we're going to keep Supergirl to ourself right now.

And then [later on](http://comicbook.com/2016/01/12/cbs-president-hints-the-flash-supergirl-crossover-might-be-in-th/), new Chairman of CBS Entertainment Glenn Geller said:

> “I have to be really careful what I say here,” Geller said on the Television Critics Association press tour. "Watch and wait and see what happens,” he concluded.

So, it's a mystery whether or not *Supergirl* can and will crossover with the other shows.

Comment: Related quote: Berlanti said ["I think in success, all things are possible,"](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/05/18/arrow-and-the-flash-producer-gives-update-on-supergirl-crossover-potential) indicating that if the show does well and the fans want a crossover, a crossover might *become* possible when previously it hadn't been.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, as of Feb 3, 2016, the shows ***are*** part of the same fictional universe. (Note that the Arrowverse itself already includes a DC-comics-like incarnation of a multi-verse; it's highly likely that Kara Kent and Barry Allen will be from different internally-defined Earths, but part of the same externally-defined fictional reality.)

We have known for a while that this was [a possibility](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/agent-carter-showrunners-grilled-by-759932), as the shows are produced by the same group of people, and CBS partially owns the CW. Originally the network execs were [less enthusiastic](http://movieweb.com/supergirl-arrow-flash-tv-crossover-cbs/) to the idea, but when *Supergirl*'s full-season pickup was announced, it was accompanied by rumors that a crossover might happen.

It has now been confirmed:

> CBS announced today that Grant Gustin’s Flash will be crossing over into an episode of Supergirl later this year—a development that’s sure to please fans of both series. While details of what the crossover will entail are yet to be revealed, the episode is set to air on Monday, March 28th. <sup><sub>[src](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2016/02/03/breaking-news-the-flash-is-crossing-over-with-supergirl)</sub></sup>

Assuming there are no off-weeks, March 28th would be S01E20 of *Supergirl*, but no other details about that episode are known; the announcement also doesn't mention of the crossover will be reciprocal (e.g. there's no information that Kara Danvers will appear on the CW Arrowverse shows.) However, the description of the crossover as:

> Grant Gustin for making the time to come visit

strongly implies that this one, at least, will be a one-way crossover.

Comment: I was holding out hope that it wouldn't happen, sadly it is.

Comment: Well, the good thing at least is that it definitively allows for Superman in the Arrowverse.

Comment: On another note, at the February 9th episode of The Flash, supergirl is seen in an image (Spoilers ahead: She's seen when Barry/Cisco/Harry travel from Earth 1 to Earth 2 and see 'everything' )

Comment: _"the shows are part of the same universe"_ I think this is a misleading statement! Barry is going to have to cross into a different Universe to meet Kara.

Comment: 1. We don't actually *know* that for sure, though it's pretty likely, and 2. Yes, we're using universe in the sense of a fictional umbrella existence. In other words: they exist in the same reality as each other and can interact.

Comment: @Robert There's already been a subtle reference to both Superman and Batman in Legends of Tomorrow, so I'm sort of hoping we might get to see at least one of them at some point.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist as am I.  I actually have a theory that DC really is connecting the TV and Cinematic universes.  It's pretty outlandish, but it kind of makes sense once you think about it.

Comment: Flash and  Arrow are on Earth-1; Kara is from Earth-38. Her universe may get coalesced into Earth-1 if they ever do the TV version of _Crisis on Infinite Earths_

Answer (score 1):

After the events of *Crisis on Infinite Earths* which was a five-part crossover event of the Arrowverse consisting of the shows:

- Arrow
- Flash
- Batwoman
- Black Lightning
- Legends of Tomorrow

these shows were all made into a single Earth known as **Earth Prime** making all the shows happen on same Earth. Thus Supergirl is now officialy part of same universe as well as same Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they open up another Verse, along with Earth 2, then I can not see how.
Superman has been active for years in the Supergirl universe and would you think that would have to have been referenced by now in Arrow (especially as the whole meta-human phenomena has only started occurring and is news to everyone that "abilities" exist)

In "Legends" there is reference to Men of Steel and Dark Knights, so potentially open in future episodes to have Supes come into Earth 1

Comment: I see no reason to presume other Earths can't be reached from the Arrowverse now. They've shown that it's possible to make at least one reachable.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with the fact that they have shown Supergirl in Flash already, in the months since the answer?

Comment: How does it have nothing to do with that? That moment in the first season finale was the first proof that my comment has merit! (Though until the actual crossover happens it's not firm proof that the universe can be "reached".)

Comment: Sarcasm detector malfunction