# Is Jamillah Olsen on "Black Lightning" a reference to Jimmy Olsen?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, black-lightning-2018

In the season three premiere of *Black Lightning*, the audience is introduced to the character of Jamillah Olsen, a journalist investigating the goings-on of Freeland.

I may be grasping at straws here, but was her name/occupation a conscious reference to Jimmy Olsen (Superman's pal)? Both are journalists (although Jimmy is more of a photographer initially) and shared the name J. Olsen.

Was this intentional on the part of the creators or simply a happy coincidence?

Comment: Of course it's a reference :-)

Comment: Has something changed since [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180356/is-black-lightning-part-of-the-arrowverse?rq=1) was asked and answered to warrant the [tag:arrowverse] tag?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I mean, Supergirl is part of the Arrowverse despite being in another universe. Besides, since that question was asked, it was announced that Black Lightning will be included in the Crisis on Infinite Earths crossover somehow, although it is not currently known in what capacity.